# How do I place vertical GridLines in front of horizontal ones?

Tags: graphics, options, customization

By default horizontal GridLines are placed in front of vertical GridLines:

```
style = Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[5]] &;
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> style /@ #] & /@ {{LightGray, Black}, {Black, LightGray}} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**How can I place the vertical lines in front so that they appear uninterrupted?**

I do not wish to resort to manually drawing `Line` expressions.

Comment: Uhh, much better :-)  Remindeth me of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_illusion

Answer (score 4):

This at least gets the result:

```
style = Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[5]] &;
Overlay[
    {Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1,
      GridLines -> Automatic,
      GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {#1, #2}],
     Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1,
      GridLines -> Automatic,
      GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {#1, Opacity[0]}]}] & @@@
  {{LightGray, Black}, {Black, LightGray}} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

More a workaround rather than a solution, but simple and maybe useful with some pre-planning of data and such:

```
Rotate[Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {LightGray, Black}], 90 Degree]
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit this method did not occur to me. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible way by `Inset`, but I'm still not very sure why it's `2.1`:

```
style = Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[5]] &;

Graphics[{Opacity[0], Circle[]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], ImagePadding -> 1, 
  GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {Opacity[0], Black}];

Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1, 
  GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {LightGray, Opacity[0]}];

Show[%%, Epilog -> Inset[%, Center, {0, 0}, {2.1, Automatic}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

According to the documentation of `PlotRangePadding`:

> PlotRangePadding->Automatic adds a total of 4% for PlotRange settings All, Full, and Automatic.

It should be $2\times (1+4\%)=2.08$, but in fact `2.08` will be worse than `2.1` here. Don't know why...

Comment: You need 2.1 to allow for the default `PlotRangePadding`.  With the option `PlotRangePadding -> None` you could set it to 2.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen But why 2.1 instead of 2.08?

Comment: I think the `ImagePadding -> 1` options throw it off.  Remove them and try `Show[%%, Epilog -> Inset[%, Center, {0, 0}, {2.08, Automatic}], ImagePadding -> 0]`.  (If I don't put in the `ImagePadding -> 0` the frame is clipped, and I don't know why.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hmm.. interesting.. I tried changing the `ImagePadding`, but didn't seem to affect the `2.1` value. Get a flight to fly. Will review it tomorrow night.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll put on paper a simple fix that works only with the gray/black lines as shown rather than being a general solution.  (Desiring a general solution was the reason I originally used the garish colored lines that Yves complained about.)

```
style = Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[5]] &;

Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {Black, Opacity[0.3]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plainly this won't work with other combinations (warning: garish colors):

```
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 1, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> style /@ {Yellow, {Green, Opacity[0.3]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]